# C# HttpWebRequest returning 500 Internal Error

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, web, internal-server-error

I would like to know why my HTTP Request returned an 500 Server Internal Error on the Response.

I use this C# Code

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://svabyss.66ghz.com/getmsg.php");
req.ContentLength = ("receiver=" + b.ToString() + "&PHPSESSID=" + _SESSIONID).Length;
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Method = "POST";
req.KeepAlive = true;
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Pragma] = "cache";
req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
req.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://svabyss.66ghz.com:80", true);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write("receiver=" + b.ToString() + "&PHPSESSID=" + _SESSIONID);
writer.Flush();
writer.Dispose();
try
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    OperationCompleted(new SVWorkerEventArgs("GET|" + b.ToString(), reader.ReadToEnd()));
    response.Close();
    reader.Dispose();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    StreamReader str = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream());
    string err = str.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I dont know wich header i missed. ANy help would be great !

thanks..

PROBLEM FIXED

I received the reply via error message returned by the server. The error message is actually the result i want.

Now, i dont care what the server replying to me. Wether its 404 or 505, the error message returned is what i want..

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Have you tried it without the `Proxy`?

Comment: Why are you specifying all of those settings?

Comment: My first code is just

    `req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`

Only these Headers value i set, and its returned the same error

Answer (score 1):

The 500 error code is returned because the server (not your client) experienced an internal error.  To find out what the error is, you would need access to the server's logs, or need to ask someone who has access.

It is *entirely possible* that the error is caused by something in your code, but without knowing what the error is on the other end, there's no way for you to be sure.  It could just as easily be something in their code, or a connection to their databse, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make the request with a browser while running Fiddler:
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Look at the header used there.

Comment: `POST http://svabyss.66ghz.com/getmsg.php?receiver=putra HTTP/1.1`

`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

`User-Agent: abyss`

`Host: svabyss.66ghz.com`

`Content-Length: 42`
`Expect: 100-continue`

`PHPSESSID=119f0d7a53a2d8e30282701d5ca856bd`

Thats is the fiddler header request RAW. I dont have any idea whats happening there..

Comment: Do you have control of the target page? or it it owned by someone else? also, i'd try appending the Query string in WebRequest.Create("http://svabyss.66ghz.com/getmsg.php");